# A simple email autoresponder

Tags: command-line, scripts, automation, mail

I have a POP3 email account, that I do not use anymore. It is on a server out of my control.

Several of my contacts keep on sending email to that address, though I told them. So I decided to set an autoresponse saying "I do not read at this address anymore, write to that other address".

I need a little process running on one of my always-up machines that fetches emails from the server and answers, to that coming from one of my contact, with a standard response.

I am looking for a solution simple to setup, like fetchmail + mailx + some bash scripting.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer here?

Comment: @BlueXrider: yes, I am

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to set up an email autoresponder using thunderbird :

1. Click on **write**, and compose you response.
2. Save it as a **template**
3. Go to **tools**, **message filters**
4. Select your inbox and click on **new**
5. Select **match all messages**
6. In the action dialog select **reply with template**

Et voilà!

Now each time you will check your mail it will send your template to every person that sent you a mail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe my question was not clear, but I am looking for a solution that could work unattended on server without a GUI.

Comment: Oh, do you think [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-autoresponder-with-autoresponse) could help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I do not want to install a GUI and thunderbird only for this task

Comment: no no I meant the link I gave in the comment

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see the link. I'm reading, let me the time to understand. Also, you can edit your answer to mention that link, too